# How to disable Developer options on Moto E4 without clearing settings storage data?

Tags: settings, developer-options, app-data, motorola-moto-e4

In order to speed up my Moto E4 (Android 7.1.1), I followed this advice:

Settings > About phone > Build number (tapped about 3 times) which enabled Developer options. Then hit the back button >  Developer options.

One by one I opened three animation scales and brought them down to .5x:

- Window animation
- Transition animation
- Animator duration

Then at the top of the screen I turned Developer Options off. However, it is still available now in my settings menu when previously it was not (before I hit "Build number" 3 times).

When I did this I didn't realize that I was opening a mode that wouldn't just close back when I was done. In searching for how to disable what I enabled, I read that I can disable developer options (remove it from the settings menu) by going to:

Settings > Apps > Settings > Storage > Clear Data

However, I am hesitant to do that because it says:

```
All this app's data will be deleted permanently. 
This includes all files, settings, accounts, databases, etc
```

I'm not sure what files are included and how that will affect my phone.  It's only 700 kb though.

Is there another way that I can disable/close the Developer options that I inadvertently opened? If not, how can I know what the affect will be when I clear the settings storage data?

Thanks!

Comment: I just found an answer here that might apply to me but the build number is so much older and isn't the same device, so I will leave my question unless it is a confirmed duplicate.

Comment: after you have enabled developer options, and when in developer options, you get a toggle button to disable it. Otherwise, goto settings and clear cache and data of 'Settings ' application.

Comment: @RahulGopi Thank you. Yes, I mentioned that I did toggle to disable but that didn't remove it from settings.  I was asking if there was another way to remove it from settings without  clearing data of the settings application.

Comment: By doing above step, it will only affect settings app only. It doesn't affect with files, accounts, databases.

Comment: @RahulGopi that's what I needed to know. Now I'm thinking that I should reword my question so that someone else can benefit. The reason I was hesitant to follow the steps is because I thought that I would delete other stuff. Other people seem to be confused too.